# General error when trying to insert data into database

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to insert data into a database and once again I cant seem to get to the bottom as to why I am getting a general error.

Any advice as to how to overcome this problem.

```
Class.forName(driverName);
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(SourceURL, user, password);
int rowAdded;

Object typeId = comboKeys.getSelectedItem();
String typeIdString = typeId.toString();
int typeIdInt = Integer.parseInt(typeIdString);

String animalIDString = txtAnimalID.getText();
int animalID = Integer.parseInt(animalIDString);
System.out.println(animalID);
String name = txtName.getText();

Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
String queryString = "INSERT INTO Animal (animalID, name, typeIDForeign) VALUES (" + animalID + ", '" + name + "', '" + typeIdInt + "')";

rowAdded = statement.executeUpdate(queryString);
connection.close();
```

Kind regards

Arian

Comment: what error are you getting ? stacktrace pls...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Error

You have `typeIdInt` as `Integer`, however in the sql query, you are stating it as string (because you surround it with single quotes)

### Solution

`String queryString = "INSERT INTO Animal (animalID, name, typeIDForeign) VALUES (" + animalID + ", '" + name + "', '" + typeIdInt + "')";`

**should be :**

`String queryString = "INSERT INTO Animal (animalID, name, typeIDForeign) VALUES (" + animalID + ", '" + name + "', " + typeIdInt + ")";`

Look at `" + typeIdInt + "`. You have `'" + typeIdInt + "'`

### Good Luck!!!